# FOSUserBundle: Remember last page before login

Tags: authentication, symfony-2.1, fosuserbundle

Is there an easy way to configure FOSUserBundle to remember the page a User came from before login?
I don't want Users to end up on the Startpage after they already browsed to what they are interested in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to configure how the user is redirected after a login. See this document for details:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login.html

This applies to Symfony in general, but it will work the same if you are using FOSUserBundle